# Command line processing - tokens and metacharacters

Tags: shell

I am just learning about command line processing, and hoping someone can confirm how I am interpreting the following statement. In the book I am reading the first step in command line processing is:

> 1. Splits the command into tokens that are separated by the fixed set of metacharacters: *SPACE*, *TAB*, *NEWLINE*, `;`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `|`, and `&`. Types of tokens include words, keywords, I/O redirectors, and semicolons

Am I right in thinking that  for  the command:

`ls | more`

`ls` and `more` are the tokens, and the `pipe` character is the `meta character` separating the two tokens?

I got bit confused as it goes on to say that `<` and `>` are `meta characters`, but then says that tokens can be `I/O directors`.

Comment: In practice, an isolated metacharacter (like `|`) or some sequences of them(like `||` or `>&`) will also constitute tokens; that's why the sentence goes on to say that redirectors (`>`, `<`, `>&`, and so on) are tokens. But the sentence in your book isn't formulated in a way to acknowledge this. I agree with you that as it's written, the metacharacters aren't themselves tokens. The sentence as written is incorrect.

Comment: it depends a great deal on the shell's current parse level. basically, the words aren't tokens until they're tokenized - the shell just stacks them a character at a time as it reads until it encounters one of your *metacharacters* - each of which is a recognizable token unto itself at that point - and the shell can call all that its stacked so far a *token*.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a very good explanation. A *token* is a sequence of characters that forms a word or punctuation sign. Characters like `<` and `|` are part  of tokens too. You may call them metacharacters but this is not useful terminology. The basic rules are:

- Whitespace is not part of a token and separates tokens.
- A token is made up of ordinary characters, or of operator characters `()<>&|;`, but not both. For example, `foo<@a&>b` consists of the tokens `foo` (ordinary), `<` (operator), `@a` (ordinary), `&>` (operator) and `b`.

Then there are additional rules about quoting: special characters lose their meaning if they're quotes, with different rules depending on the type of quote. For example, `foo'&&'bar\|qux` is a single token with the character sequence `foo&&bar|qux`.