# Whether whitespace be defined as token in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Bash Reference Manual says

> - '*token*' is either a '*word*' or an '*operator*'.
> - '*Words*' may not include unquoted '*metacharacters*'.
> - '*Space*' is one of the '*metacharacters*' but not'*operator*'.

So an unquoted *space* is not *token*?

How muck Tokens does the cmd "echo word;echo 'word and word'"have?

Comment: Is this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234914/72456 answering your question?

Comment: Can u tell me the number of tokens in " echo word;echo 'word and word' "

Comment: Are the surrounding quotes part of the string ? If not, 4 tokens

Comment: @JackWalter Six tokens, counting the newline at the end, and counting operator tokens the way a parser would return them.

Comment: @GillesQuenot not 5?'echo','word',';','echo','word and word'?

Comment: @Kusalananda   sorry,my fault,the newline is not part of the string.now 5 is right?

Comment: Ah yes, 5, forgotten the `;` token

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework question...

Comment: @0xSheepdog - "Question was moved to homework.stackexchange.com"...LOL

Comment: @0xSheepdog lol,cuz the 'token' trans to chinese doesnt have correct meaning.